# ActiveRecord includes to_json doesn't include relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model find like this for an API:

```
Article.includes(:comments).all
```

When applying the `to_json` method, I'd like to get back the article along with an array of the comments. Unfortunately, the to_json method only returns the Article model. Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this :

```
Article.includes(:comments).find(your_article_id).to_json(:include => :comments)
```

using all on the model will fetch every single article available in the database.
using to_json on a relation should get you a json array of all records returned by the relation as json.

you can get additional info **[here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)**.

Comment: Hope this is helpful for anyone else coming here looking for the answer, if you're using Rails to respond with JSON and want to include an association, there's another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730121/include-associated-model-when-rendering-json-in-rails